# googlecharts not loading json data when run on local server

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

I'm planning to use googlecharts to chart data that is stored on in a local database - the googlecharts code will also be stored on a local server. I used  XAMPP to create a local directory ('http://http://127.0.0.1/). Before jumping into the project, I am testing an example script (that I found from a google search) that takes data from a json file (which is called from a php script) and then feeds it to the googlecharts drawing functions. The 3 files are all stored in the folder 'C:\xampp\htdocs', as advised, but when I load the page in my browser (http://127.0.0.1/test_php_long.html) the page appears blank (on Chrome, IE and Firefox). When I run a googlecharts script with data hardcoded into the HTML it works fine. I have been looking online for several hours but have yet to find a solution that works.

This is the main html file ('test_php_long.html'):

```
<html>
       <head>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.maxcdn.com/one//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">    
          google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});      
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);      
          function drawChart() {
            var jsonData = $.ajax({
      //fetchjson.php is a php script that will fetch the JSON data e generated using above php code
               url: "fetchjson.php",
               dataType:"json",
               async: false
               }).responseText;
           var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
           var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_flow'));
           chart.draw(data, {width: 1200, height: 300, lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 1.3, pointWidth: 3});
          }
      </script>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div id="chart_flow"></div>
       </body>
</html>
```

This is the php file ('fetchjson.php')

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
      //Fill the ‘string’ variable with JSON data from file we used as json container populated by php //code: ‘flow.json’
      $string = file_get_contents("flow.json");
      //push JSON data out
      echo $string;
      ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

And this is the json file ('flow.json'):

{"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Time","pattern":"","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"Cache Hits","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"Non-Cache Hits","pattern":"","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21 00:00:00"},{"v":2},{"v":23}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21 01:00:00"},{"v":2},{"v":52}]},
      ...
      ,{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-23 01:00:00"},{"v":0},{"v":34}]},]}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be related to the fact that your request is a cross-origin one, or at least being considered as once. There are two ways as far as I know to deal with this issue, either you allow cross origin requests, by adding the following lines at the top of your PHP script :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
```

While this is potentially unsafe, and the * should be replaced by a list of trusted domains, it should solve your problem for now and shouldn't be much of a security threat since your app will be running in an intranet.

OR, you could also issue jsonp instead of json by wrapping your json object in a callback :

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($something_to_be_encoded) . ')';
```

Don't forget that your url parameter passed to your ajax function should now be :

```
http://myawesomescript.php?callback=?
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Ashwin. It seems that the data in the json file was causing problems. Still not quite sure why but I got another json file to work within my set up without needing to add the cross origin requests.

Comment: Since your chart was functioning with your json data I assumed it was in the correct format :) Didn't bother to test it. ANyway, glad it worked out. Cheers